# Authorisation error in snowflake while connecting using python

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
import snowflake.connector
#create connection
conn=snowflake.connector.connect( user='', url = '', 
 password='',account='',warehouse='',database='',schema='')
#create cursor
CS = conn.cursor()
conn.cursor().execute("USE ROLE ")
#conn.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA ")
CS.execute("alter external table demo_data refresh")
```

I am getting error like SQL compilation error: External table 'A_PQSN_342_JUI_01.DBA.DEMO_DATA' does not exist or not authorized. Can you please help in this issue

Comment: Are you using a role that has rights to alter that external table?

Answer (score 0):

Only the external table owner (i.e. the role with the OWNERSHIP privilege on the external table) or higher can execute this command: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-external-table.html#usage-notes

So most probably your role has insufficient privileges to alter the table.

Or the table is really not existing :-)